# Unable to Open new browser after each scenario in Cucumber-Protractor

Tags: protractor, cucumberjs

I had automated all my scenarios using cucumber-protractor framework. All this scenarios run fine when executed individually i.e. closes the browser once scenario is complete but when ran together I am unable to open new browser window after each scenario. It just continues in same browser. Due to SSO login, I have to restart browser after each scenario.

I tried using maxSession, maxInstance in protractor but of no help. Though maxIntance opens new browser, it doesn't close old one and neither passes control to new one. I tried using getWindowHandler as well but that also didn't worked.

Any help is greatly appreciated as I am stuck on this for long time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems juliemr answers your question:

> tests are sharded by file, not by scenario, so you'll need to split the scenarios into separate files.

https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/864#issuecomment-45571006

So you'll need to split the scenarios into separate feature files and, if desired, set `maxInstances` to however many you want to run at once. For example:

```
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'shardTestFiles': true,
    'maxInstances': 10
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a hook after each scenario to close the browser:

```
this.After(function(scenario, done) {
  this.quit(done);
});
```